# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unsupported Media Type when i use SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

So i'm trying to get an appropriate response from the wsdl API but i keep getting the same error

> "Unsupported Media type"

```
 $opts = array(
'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/soap+xml'
    )
  );
 $ctx = stream_context_create($ctx_opts);

     $options = array( 
            'soap_version'=>'SOAP_1_1', 
            'stream_context' => $ctx,
            'keep_alive' => true
          ); 
    $params = array(
            'UserId'=>'xxxx',
            'Password'=>'xxxx',
            'PassKey'=>'xxxxx'
           );
      $client = new SoapClient('http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc?wsdl',$options);
      $response = $client->getPassword($params);
```

I've tried changing the **SOAP** version to both `SOAP 1.1` and `SOAP 1.2` and even use `text/xml` as my `Content-type` but that does seem to work either throwing the same error. **Any suggestions?**

Comment: I haven't used the `stream_context` option before. Have you tried it without those options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. it was because i set SOAP 1_2 in quotes when actually it's a predefined constant.